# Why \printglossary doesn't work with \cleardoublepage at the end? (2xpdflatex)

Tags: glossaries

`printglossary` doesn't work, if i used `\cleardoublepage` at the end of my document.

If i add some text after `\cleardoublepage` everything works as expected. I cannot explain to myself why.

If i used `glossaries-extra` instead of `glossaries` i get this **error message**, which describes the problem. Why it depends of text after `\cleardoublepage` or not? :

---

[image]

Hope someone could help.

**MWE:** (compiled twice with pdflatex) -- DOES NOT WORK

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,automake,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}
%%\usepackage[acronym,automake,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{A}{type=\acronymtype, name={letter A},description={Long text}}
\begin{document}
First use of \gls{A}.
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\cleardoublepage
%some text
\end{document}
```

**MWE:** (compiled twice with pdflatex) -- DOES WORK

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,automake,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}
%%\usepackage[acronym,automake,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{A}{type=\acronymtype, name={letter A},description={Long text}}
\begin{document}
First use of \gls{A}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\cleardoublepage
some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the delayed `\write18` made by `glossaries.sty`'s `\@gls@automake` command is lost at the end of the document.

My initial thought was to add `\immediate`, which can be done in this patch:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,automake,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@gls@automake}[1]{%
  \ifglossaryexists{#1}%
  {%
    \@closegls{#1}%
    \ifdefstring{\glsorder}{letter}%
     {\def\@gls@order{-l }}%
     {\let\@gls@order\@empty}%
    \immediate\write18{makeindex \@gls@order 
      -s \istfilename\space
      -t \jobname.\csuse{@glotype@#1@log}
      -o \jobname.\csuse{@glotype@#1@in}
      \jobname.\csuse{@glotype@#1@out}}%
  }%
  {%
    \GlossariesWarning{Can't make glossary `#1', it doesn't exist}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{A}{type=\acronymtype, name={letter
A},description={Long text}}
\begin{document}
First use of \gls{A}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this means the `\write18` call is now being forced before the associated glossary files have closed, which means that `makeindex` fails:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./test.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file test.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in test.gls.
Transcript written in test.glg.
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./test.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file test.acn...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in test.acr.
Transcript written in test.alg.
```

The only solution I can think of is to put `\null` after `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,automake,nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{A}{type=\acronymtype, name={letter
A},description={Long text}}
\begin{document}
First use of \gls{A}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\cleardoublepage\null
\end{document}
```

This results in a three page document with a blank third page, but I'm guessing that's your intention (given that you have `\cleardoublepage` at the end of the document).

Comment: I tried `\relax`(does not work) and not `\null`. But `\null` works fine! Thank you very much.

Comment: You can find a [suggestion to solve this on LC](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=32130).